# How to fix 'DataFrameIterator' object has no attribute 'class_names'?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
#Image Generator
```

- List item

  ```
       train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
       rotation_range=45,
       rescale=1./255,
       horizontal_flip=True
       )
  ```

  #Mapping
  train_data = train_gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = train_csv,
  directory = train_folder, x_col = 'image_ID',
  y_col = 'label', seed = 42,
  batch_size = 32, shuffle = True,
  class_mode="categorical",target_size = (100,100))

  ```
       imgs,lbl=next(iter(train_data))

       train_data.class_names
   AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-62-664d0b13aade> in <module>()
   ----> 1 train_data.class_names

   AttributeError: 'DataFrameIterator' object has no attribute 'class_names'
  ```

Comment: Hi @Yogesh, the train_data does not have an attribute "class_names", hence the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute 'class_names' in flow_from_dataframe. You can use `class_indices` instead to get the class names along with their indices as follows:

Here I've used cifar-10 dataset

```
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=traindf,
directory="/content/train/",
x_col="id",
y_col="label",
subset="training",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
target_size=(32,32))


train_generator.class_indices
```

Output:

```
{'airplane': 0,
 'automobile': 1,
 'bird': 2,
 'cat': 3,
 'deer': 4,
 'dog': 5,
 'frog': 6,
 'horse': 7,
 'ship': 8,
 'truck': 9}
```